# How to set custom relative date filters

Tags: civireport, search, date-preferences, dates

I noticed that the relative date filters (e.g. "This week", "Previous quarter) have some new options available in 4.7, and I heard that you can now customize them to create new options.  I don't know how to do this, though.

I see them in **Administer - System Settings - Option Groups**, but it doesn't have any definition of what they are.  Neither **Administer - Customize Data and Screens - Date Preferences** nor **Administer - Localization - Date Formats** have them.

Specifically, I'd like to add something like "Empty or prior to this year".  I know that this might be a bit much to ask even if I can customize it, but I thought I'd find where I could edit the settings.

Answer (score 3):

So I think I was jumping the gun with my excitement about this.

I found [the issue on Jira](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16195), which has been updated to say the custom filter creation has been bumped to 4.8.  The work-in-progress code that Jon was working on is at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6307